# Programmtically convert xsn to pdf in console application SP2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, pdf

Is there a way to convert infopath forms (.xsn) forms into pdf using c# console application in Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Are you looking to convert the XSN into a fillable PDF (so as a replacement for InfoPath) or are you looking to convert the XML files that have been filled out using that XSN? Also, why are you looking to do this from the command line? You mention SharePoint so wouldn't it be better / more obvious to use workflows or event receivers? (BTW, there are 3rd party apps available that specialise in InfoPath conversion, it is extremely tricky to get right, Google 'Muhimbi', we do this for a living ;-)

Comment: We have all the infopath forms in a library and want all of them converted into pdf

Comment: So you don't really need a console application, but if it is a one off thing then it is not necessarily a bad option.

Answer (score 3):

You may reference Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, then utilize the .Export

```
this.CurrentView.Export(@"C:\MyView.pdf", ExportFormat.Pdf);
```

for more details, visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.view.export.aspx

Comment: can we achieve it using console application?